# Paypal PHP API integration

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Recently I'm playing with paypal API PHP.

I have downloaded a code from this url.

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-curlsamples/blob/master/execute_all_calls.php

The code really works good with test creditcard(type:mastercard). The code looks like this

```
  $url = $host.'/v1/payments/payment';
  $payment = array(
  'intent' => 'sale',
  'payer' => array(
  'payment_method' => 'credit_card',
  'funding_instruments' => array ( array(
  'credit_card' => array (
  'number' => '540xxxxxxxxxxxx6',
  'type'   => 'mastercard',
  'expire_month' => 12,
  'expire_year' => 2018,
  'cvv2' => 111,
  'first_name' => 'First Name',
  'last_name' => 'Last Name'
  )
  ))
  ),
  'transactions' => array (array(
  'amount' => array(
  'total' => '2',
  'currency' => 'USD'
  ),
  'description' => 'payment by a credit card using a test script'
  ))
  );
```

Now if i try to use the same code to make the payment using my VISA(American Express) with test card number 37xxxxxxxxxx005, how shall i obtain this? What are the parameters to be altered?

In other words I would like to make the payment using Diner's Club,Discover and JCB. How shall I achieve this?

Edit: I have got two comments from Stack Overflow users, and you can check it at the bottom of my question. I'm not clear with the comments. Do they tell that I don't need to think about the parameters and paypal will take care of the card details and make the transaction?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the variant where YOU are given the creditcard numbers? Let PayPal handle that part and just deal with the transaction. There are _serious_ security and privacy considerations attached to handling creditcard numbers.

Comment: Much easier to let PayPal handle that information.

Comment: Campen - I have masked the dummy test c.card number. Is there anything. I'm not getting your point. Bad memory. Could you explain me something more here.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got reply from Paypal Tech Team for my above question

{snip}

You need to alter the code for 'type'. Below shows the code for the credit card type :l

```
- Visa
- MasterCard
- Discover
- Amex
```

And also make sure you need to input correct credit card number based on the type if you not you will receive an error message.

{/snip}

In other words, it is more than enough if I change the `'type'   => 'mastercard' to 'type'   => 'visa' (or) 'type'   => 'amex' (or) 'type'   => 'discover'`

And also please make sure you give the correct test card numbers. You can view the dummy credit card numbers here. 
http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Hope this will help someone if they are struck with the paypal PHP API integration.

Thanks for all the tech support & SOF-Users.

Thanks again,
Haan